# I need to convert a string into HMAC SHA1 and then base64 encode but hitting problems

Tags: node.js, nginx, cryptojs, hmacsha1

I am trying to grab a jwt cookie through an endpoint on my server.

This is the code from within nginx that builds an access token:

`local expected_token = ngx.encode_base64(ngx.hmac_sha1(token_secret, cb_server_name .. email .. expires))`

I now need to replicate that code in node but I am hitting some walls...

This is my node code:

```
const secret = process.env.TOKEN_SECRET
const cb_server_name = process.env.SERVER_NAME
const email = process.env.EMAIL
const expires = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 3600

const message = `${cb_server_name}${email}${expires}`
const encrypted = CryptoJS.HmacSHA1(message, secret)
const token = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(encrypted)

// I have also tried:
const token = encrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64)
```

When I pass the `token` with my request, I dont get the response I am looking for. I am pretty sure my Base64 encoding is wrong but I am not 100% sure. I would really appreciate the help here.

Thank you.

---

Edit:

Example of the encoded token from nginx: `goCkSE2NrZoPxMpJTo+bcU6xXhw=`
Encoded token im getting from node: `RKA4T6wfHIArtWbj5tjeSvrl21c=`

Comment: Could you include an example of the base64 encoded token generated by nginx and one generated by node? Might want to replace any sensitive information beforehand though.

Comment: I edited the original question to include some sample tokens.